# Find all points near a point within a radius MySql 8.0 (SRID 4326)

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

This question is targeted to MySQL 8.0 with its new spatial features.

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `places` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `location` POINT NOT NULL SRID 4326,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `location_idx` (`location`)
);
```

I want to retrieve all the places near to a Point *(let's call it `MY_POINT`)* within a certain distance in meters *(let's call it `MY_DISTANCE`)*, I also want to retrieve the distance within that point, and I want to do it in the most optimal way, e.g: triggering a spatial index with a `WHERE` clause.

To get the distance, I must use the `ST_Distance` function to calculate the distance between `MY_POINT` and each of the query results;
To test if the point is within `MY_DISTANCE`, I must create a circle around `MY_POINT` with `MY_DISTANCE` as a radius and then check if `MY_POINT` intersects the polygon.

This is the query I've made so far:

```
SELECT
  id,ST_Distance(MY_POINT, location) AS distance
FROM
  places
WHERE
  ST_Intersects(ST_SRID(ST_Buffer(MY_POINT, MY_DISTANCE / 111194.927), 4326), location) -- 111194.927 = degree of latitude in meters.
HAVING
  distance <= MY_DISTANCE -- This fixes the inaccurate ST_BUFFER polygon in some cases.
ORDER BY
  distance
ASC;
```

The problem is `ST_BUFFER` is making a weird and inaccurate circle (nothing to do with segments, rather I think it's because I calculate wrong the radius) and I'm missing some results.

Can anyone throw some light to this?

Comment: You have your data in lat/lng (decimal degrees) you will get the odd shapes with point buffers in northern and southern hemispheres see for an example http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/projection/ you need to buffer in meters or feet

Comment: Looks like MySQL 8 supports ST_Transform (like postgis) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-transform

Comment: @Mapperz could you elaborate, please? I've tried to use ST_Transform but it doesn't support transforming from a geometric SRID to a geographic one. (3741 - Transformation from SRID 0 is not supported.)

Comment: @Mapperz Also, ST_Buffer doesn't support buffering a geographic point, so I can't buffer a point in meters. (3618 - st_buffer(POINT, ...) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems.)